# How can i slice an array in django template?

Tags: javascript, python, django

[image]

So I am trying to achieve how to show 5 `name` into the chart instead off all `name`:

here is my `views.py`:
def index(req):

```
labels = [
    {"name": 'data'},
    {"name": 'hello'},
    {"name": 'wassup'},
    {"name": "waddddup"},
    {"name": "heyyyyy"},
    {"name": "dsfdsfd"},
    {"name": "qqqq"},
    {"name": "23f3f"},
    {"name": "23f"},
    {"name": "zzzz"},

]
values = []

def label_chart(labels):
    label_test = []
    for i in labels:
        label_test.append(i['name'])
    dataJSON = dumps(label_test)
    return dataJSON

data = {
    'data': label_chart(labels),
}

return render(req, 'index.html', data)
```

and here is my template javascript `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data_labels = JSON.parse(`{{ data | safe }}`);
    console.log(data_labels);


    var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function (data) {
            labels = data.labels
            defaultData = data.default
            setChart()
        },
        error: function (error_data) {
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })


    function setChart() {
        let y = [10, 3, 5, 9, 1];
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: data_labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: y,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I already tried to slice in python which is like this:

```
data = {
    'data': label_chart(labels)[:5],
}
```

but it will give me an error like this on browser:

> VM245:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: `dumps(label_test)` what does this do?

Comment: so when I dont have it the browser giving me this error  `VM136:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1`

Comment: You are slicing the JSON blob, not the list of labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are slicing the JSON blob, not the list of labels, you can slice the labels with:

```
data = {
    'data': label_chart(labels[:5]),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try returning list from you function `label_chart` and then slice it.

```
    def label_chart(labels):
        label_test = []
        for i in labels:
            label_test.append(i['name'])
        return label_test
    
    data = {
        'data': label_chart(labels)[:5],
    }
```